# Duplicating form for editing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a form for users to complete and a section of it is duplicatable using the code below.

```
//define template
var template = $('.duplicate-sections .form-section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('.duplicate-sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('.duplicate-sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).closest('.form-section').fadeOut(300,             function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-section').empty();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Added HTML code -

```
<div class="duplicate-sections">
            <div class="form-section">
            <?php 
                foreach ($uid as $key => $value)
{ ?>
        <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text- 
left text-sm-right">Unit Name</label>
    <input style="width:50px;" class="form-control" type="text" 
name="uid[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
<div class="col-sm-2">
<input style="width:150px;" class="form-control" type="text" name="name[]" 
value="<?php echo $unit[$key]; ?>" required>
</div>
            </div>
    <div class="form-group row">            
<label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text-left text- 
sm-right">Bought?</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
<?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('bought[]', '1', 
(array_key_exists($key, $bought) && $bought[$key] == '1'));  ?>
</div>  
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-1 
text-left">Built?</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('built[]', '1', 
(array_key_exists($key, $built) && $built[$key] == '1')); ?>
</div>  
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-1 text- 
left">Primed?</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('primed[]', '1', 
(array_key_exists($key, $primed) && $primed[$key] == '1')); ?>
</div>          
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-1 text- 
left">Painted?</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('painted[]', '1', 
(array_key_exists($key, $painted) && $painted[$key] == '1')); ?>
</div>  
            <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-1 
text-left">Based?</label>
<div class="col-sm-1">
    <?php echo tep_draw_checkbox_field('based[]', '1', 
(array_key_exists($key, $based) && $based[$key] == '1')); ?>
</div>   
</div>
                <?php } ?>
                </br>       
        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text- 
left text-sm-right"></label><input class="remove col-sm-9" type="button" 
value="Remove Unit"></input>
      </div>
        </div>
        <label for="inputFirstName" class="col-form-label col-sm-3 text- 
left text-sm-right"></label><input class="addsection col-sm-9" 
type="button" value="Add Unit"></input>
```

The form data is then stored in the database and the user can come back to edit it at a later data. Unfortunately when they do so it only gives the first line of data and when I add a section it simply duplicates the first line again.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with how you are presenting the stored form to the user again, and not like the code you have currrently shown had much to do with that.

Comment: Yes I think you're probably right, I've added my form code.

Comment: I don’t see you doing any sort of loop there? If you want to output form fields for multiple records of stored data, then there should be a loop, no?

Comment: I've added the foreach loop and updated the code. The issue I have now is when I add an new section it duplicates the current 2.

Comment: Of course it does, because you are cloning `.form-section:first` - but the `:first` is pointless here, because you are only creating _one_ of those elements to begin with. You either need to create one for each of your sections - or actually select the first element _inside_ of the single `.form-section`, that you are actually interested in.

Comment: I've solved it by having a separate section for when the form is in 'edit mode'